# correlation for two columns in dataprep library

Tags: correlation, dataprep

I wrote this code plot_correlation(df1, "Selling_Price", "Present_Price");but, I have this error:
ValueError: Metadata inference failed in `dropna`.

You have supplied a custom function and Dask is unable to
determine the type of output that that function returns.

To resolve this please provide a meta= keyword.
The docstring of the Dask function you ran should have more information.

### Original error is below:

TypeError('You cannot set both the how and thresh arguments at the same time.')

I try to find corr between two columns in a dataframe;there is not any problem for one variable,plot_correlation(df1 , 'Selling_Price') in dataprep library